# Java Array Sort

Tags: java, arrays

The question was: Write a program to initialize an array and print them in a sorted order.

Now i tried to solve it in java by taking index of max value in the array in a variable "maxIn" and then swapping it with the last index variable.
In this way swaping the max variable to the last position then last-1 then last-2 so that at the end i will get a sorted array!!

The code i wrote is given below:

```
`class ArraySort
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a={10,2,65,45,1};
        int maxInd=0;
        int j,i;

        for(i=5;i>0;i++)                    //4
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)                //0<4
            {
                if(a[j]>a[maxInd])          //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
                    maxInd=j;
            }

            j--;                //because j is 5 which is not the last index

            //swap last element with max value
            a[j]=a[j]+a[maxInd];
            a[maxInd]=a[j]-a[maxInd];
            a[j]=a[j]-a[maxInd];
        } 

        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]+"\t");
    }
}`
```

I'm getting a runtime exception as:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at ArraySort.main(28ArraySort.java:12)

Please check the code and get back to me...

Comment: `0<4` actually `i` equals to `5` here

Comment: Your outer loop starts with i =5 and i only increases. Since j < i in the inner loop you get this error message.

Comment: Do you understand what this means, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`?

Comment: i know that array max index is 4 but you can see that since i=5 the inner loop will go from j=1 to j<5 i.e. 4 so i am not reading array with index 5 and i am not using i as the index i am using j as the index of the array

Comment: and yes i know the meaning of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 5

Answer (score 0):

It is because your loop starts from 5 and adding index ++ where it should be

```
 for( i = 5; i > 0; i--)
```

and add a check i != maxInd in in if condition as it makes problem in swaping the way you are doing

```
if(a[j]>a[maxInd] && j!=maxInd){    
 maxInd=j;
}
```

for eg

```
j=4 maxInd=4 

a[j] =45 , a[maxInd]= 45
a[j] = a[j]+ a[maxInd] =90            // 90 = 45 + 45
a[maxInd] = a[maxInd] -a[j] = 0       // 0 = 90 - 90
a[j]= a[j] - a[maxInd] = 0            // 0 = 0 - 0
```

Comment: i know that array max index is 4 but you can see that since i=5 the inner loop will go from j=1 to j<5 i.e. 4 so i am not reading array with index 5 and i am not using i as the index i am using j as the index of the array

Comment: and for inner loop, when it ends j=5 so i have already decremented it so that i can use j=4 or less

Comment: you can compile it by setting i=4 but same exception is coming (same for j<i-1)